# JQuery: Disable click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to disable all click events on my page but some of events are still getting called, suppose I have html as below

```
<div id='parent'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type = 'text'/></td>
            <td><select><option>A</option><option>B</option></select></td>
            <td><a href='#' onclick="alert('Called')">Click </a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>dscsdcd</td>
            <td>dscsdcd</td>
            <td>dscdscdsc</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>sdcdsc</td>
            <td>dssdcdsc</td>
            <td><input type='submit' value='Button'/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And script as below

```
$('#parent').click( function(e)
{
     e.stopPropagation();
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopImmediatePropagation();
     return false;
});
```

when I click anchor tag, it alerts `Called` which it shouldn't because I am disabling event for it's parent. Looks like anchor tag is overriding `onclick`, if it is then how to prevent it? if not, then what could be the solution?

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p7w1eemy/)

Comment: it should be `$('#parent a')....`

Comment: events propagate **UP** from `a` to the parent. so events tidied to `a` will fire first.

Comment: @ThinkDifferent  but if it was other element then? basically I want to disable it for any element under that div.

Comment: @BG101 thanks for information, but can I disable that behavior? because this scenario is quit practicle.

Comment: Just added a plugin below which allows you to disabled (remove) and enable (re-add) click events for both onclick and jquery click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onclick` attribute has a higher priority here. You can loop your `<a>` elements and unset this attribute:

```
$('#parent a').each(function () {
  $(this).attr('onclick', '');
}).click(function () {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: if I want to enable click again, can I do it programmatically?

Comment: Store `$(this).attr('onclick')` value and assign it back.

Answer (score 5):

Just remove the `onclick` attribute from elements that have it, and unbind the 'click' event using `.off('click')` method

```
$('#parent *[onclick]').removeAttr('onclick').off('click');
```

Comment: if I want to enable click again, can I do it programmatically?

Comment: This is removing, not disabling.

Comment: @Imad, you can just bind it again using .on('click'...)

Comment: @BG101, check it before commenting, the .removeAttr() removes the attribute, and then the .off('click') unbinds the click event.

Answer (score 1):

try this plugin to temporary disable `onclick` AND jQuery `click` events:-

```
$.fn.disableClick = function (disable){
    this.each(function() {
        if(disable){
            if(this.onclick)
                $(this).data('onclick', this.onclick).removeAttr('onclick');
            if($._data(this, 'events') && $._data(this, 'events').click)
                $(this).data('click', $.extend(true, {}, $._data(this, 'events').click)).off('click');
        }
        else{
            if($(this).data('onclick'))
                this.onclick = $(this).data('onclick');
            if($(this).data('click'))
                for(var i in $(this).data('click'))
                    $(this).on('click', $(this).data('click')[i].handler);
        }
    });
    return this;
};


//disable clicks
$('#parent *').disableClick(true);

//enable clicks
$('#parent *').disableClick(false);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/p7w1eemy/8/)**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable it for any element under that div you must type:

```
$('#parent *').click( function(e)
{
     e.stopPropagation();
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopImmediatePropagation();
     return false;
});
```

Comment: this is not **guaranteed**, as it depends what order events are bound to an element

Comment: @BG101 means it is not possible to prevent child clicks through parent?

Comment: No, you can prevent child clicks through parent. @BG101 say in this case you must be carefully with order of events are bound to an element.

Answer (score 0):

There is an attribute you should use to make all things disabled.

```
var nodes = document.getElementById("parent").getElementsByTagName('*');
for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
     nodes[i].disabled = true;
}
```

Unfortunately disable is not valid with anchor tags.

There you should use :

```
var nodes = document.getElementById("parent").getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
  nodes[i].onclick = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // YOUR CODES HERE
  }
}
```

try to combine these two methods according to your needs