# How to disable and then re-enable onclick event in <img> using jquery

Tags: html, jquery, image, onclick, jquery-events

I have used an image instead of button, now I want to disable the `onclick()` event in some case as we disable a button. I tried many ways but doesn't work. Below is what I did:

```
<img title="Ok" class="mtbtn"id="upd_1" onclick="add_edited('1','MM');" src="/project/images/green_ok.gif" border="0">
```

The jQuery code is:

```
$("#upd_1").css('opacity','0.5');
$("#upd_1").unbind("click");
```

I also tried:

`$("#upd_1").css('pointer-events','none');` and `document.getElementById('upd_1').style.pointerEvents = 'none';`.

Any solution?

Comment: Ok so once you `unbind` the click event how do you want it back? Or by what way do you want it again to be clickable?

Comment: then i rebind it, but the problem is unbinding. i mean i can't unbind the click event.

Comment: Ok i understood that but i am asking in what way do you rebind?

Comment: i think you can use an if statement and return the function incase it matches to the 'case' you're refering to.

Comment: I created a plugin for this in a previous [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369265/jquery-disable-click-event/33371327#33371327)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#upd_1").on('click',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: In what senario do u want to unbind click event? Can you use if statement instead of unbinding click?

Comment: ya as i suggested in the comments of question. try an if statement

Answer (score 0):

One hint is that you can give your click event a suffix so you can be sure it's the only event you are affecting. To bind:

```
$('#elementId').on('click.myevent', function () {
    // your code
}
```

To unbind:

```
$('#elementId').off('click.myevent');
```

Answer (score 0):

Not going into binding or unbinding the click event but how about creating a mask for the image. Hide the mask when you want the image to be clickable else show it.

```
img onclick="alert('clicked')" src="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/mjejVTJKT4ABNKq2HGlkDs36f-QvzI2hKFER098vBIgiAoZ2H-SN5QPvFaZEVDZRxfujrS6pszZ_J-_di2F57w0IFE3KAciDwGAh-9RcCA=s660" alt="" />
<div id="mask"></div>

<script>
$('#mask').hide();
$('#disable').click(function() {
  $('#mask').show();
});
$('#enable').click(function() {
  $('#mask').hide();
});
</script>
```

Try the Plnkr: [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jYZXjwnwbzJGolAegOKo?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. Add your parameters in two attributes (data-a and data-b for example).

```
<img title="Ok" class="mtbtn"id="upd_1" data-a="1" data-b="MM" src="/project/images/green_ok.gif" border="0">
```

Then change your javascript in this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#upd_1").bind("click", function(){
        var a = $(this).data("a");
        var b = $(this).data("b");

        // Code here

        $(this).unbind("click");
    });
});
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/73zdyusb/) the result.

Alternative is this:

```
var semaphore = true;
function add_edited (a, b) {
    if (semaphore) {
        semaphore = false;

        // Code here
    }
}
```

Create a semaphore to manage the execution of the code to the click.

Comment: it works, but not for me because i have to use onclick event

Answer (score 0):

i understood you'r problem, there is no need to `unbind()` and re `bind()` the onclick event, you can simply remove and re-add onclick attribute using `removeAttr()` and `attr()`

```
<img title="Ok" class="mtbtn"id="upd_1" onclick="add_edited('1','MM');" src="/project/images/green_ok.gif" border="0">
```

JQuery:

```
$("#upd_1").css('opacity','0.5');
$("#upd_1").removeAttr('onclick');
```

to re add onclick event do the following:

```
$("#upd_1").css('opacity','1');
$("#upd_1").attr("onclick","add_edited('1','MM');");
```

that is all you need to do.