# disabling jQuery OnClick event until checkbox is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I seem to be having some trouble here, as I have found something that allows me to disable hrefs, but they are overriden by jQuery OnClick, meaning they are still clickable? The code I have currently is as follows below, but basically I'm using a shortcode to pull the ahref below, and I need to disable all of the links until a checkbox is ticked, can anybody help me out here?

ahref

```
<a class="price_link" href="javascript:void();" onclick="window.open('https://bookings.pontins.com/sraep/www700.pgm?LINKID=700&amp;aid=&amp;offer=DSTC&amp;url=https://bookings.pontins.com/sraep/&amp;cater=SC&amp;centre=BRE&amp;Nights=3&amp;startdate=12022016&amp;apartment=Popular','Book','location=no,scrollbars=yes,width=750,height=900')">£60</a>
```

jQuery

```
// bind the click-handler:
$(".price_link").click(function(e){
    // prevent the default action of clicking on a link:
    e.preventDefault();
    // if the element with id 'check' is checked:
    if (document.getElementById('check').checked){
        // change the window.location to the 'href' of the clicked-link:
        window.location = this.href;
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you paste you HTML code also.
Or give in JSFiddle

Comment: Can we see your DOM with the checkbox ?

Comment: Can you try this: `$(".price_link").off("click").click(function(e){` or `$(".price_link").removeAttr("onclick").click(function(e){`

Comment: use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369265/jquery-disable-click-event/33371327#33371327) plugin and add a change event to the checkbox to add/remove the events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer to a similar question:
[Disable link using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091168/disable-a-link-using-css)

To summarize:

You could have a CSS rule

```
 .not-active {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}
```

and add the class `.not-active` to the proper `links` in your HTML.
Then you could listen for `change` on your `checkbox` (it is important to not `toggle` but `add` or `remove` the class since some browsers cache inputs):

```
$('#yourCheckboxId').on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).prop('checked') === true) {
        $('.price-link').removeClass('not-active');
    } else {
        $('.price-link').addClass('not-active');
    }
});
```

If you can't add the `class` in you HTML you could either surround the `link` with a `span` and apply the class to that or apply the `class` to the `link` on page-load:

```
$(function() {
    $('.price-link').addClass('not-active');
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I have just tried this, and it works other than I have to tick the box to disable them, how can I flip it around?

Comment: Happy to help :) - In your HTML you have to add the class `not-active` to all **links** with the class `price-link`. (So it might look something like this: `<a class="price-link not-active" ...>...</a>`)

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying - can I wrap this around there by any chance? As we can't add classes directly to the shortcode which looks like [pricex oc="DSTC" y="2016" m="02" d="15" pk="Brean Sands" nts="4" cat="SC"]?

Comment: for example, can I use maybe a span around it and add the class to that instead?

Comment: Yes, the `link` would be disabled if the rule were applied to a `span` surrounding it.

Comment: Or you could apply the `class` to the `link` on page-load via JS.

Comment: I just remembered that Firefox caches `input`s - therefore the `class` should be `add`ed or `remove`d and not `toggle`d.

Answer (score 1):

Test if your checkbox is checked (`$('#checkbox').prop("checked")`) and react accordingly:

```
$('.price_link').click(function(){
  if ($('#yourCheckboxId').prop("checked") != true)
    return; //do nothing if your checkbox isn't chekced

  //do what you want to do if your checkbox is checked here
});
```

Comment: I added the `!= true` on the if just to emphasize that prop returns a boolean

Comment: I have just tried this, but the links still click through for me :(

Comment: @StuartPontins Remove the onclick from the link, add the window.open inside the click handler

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
$(".price_link").click(function(e){
    if (document.getElementById('check').checked){
        window.location = this.href;
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

or this?

```
$(".price_link").click(function(e){
    if (!document.getElementById('check').checked){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class `.not-active` to all your links with rules to disable them. Then use a simple `.click()` function that tests if your checkbox is checked and removes/adds the `.not-active` class accordingly.

```js
$('#checkboxId').click(function() {
  if ($('#checkboxId').prop('checked') == true) {
    $('.price_link').removeClass('not-active');
  } else {
    $('.price_link').addClass('not-active');
  }
});
```

```css
.not-active {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<p><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxId">Activate all links?</p>

<a href="#" class="price_link not-active">Link 1</a><br>
<a href="#" class="price_link not-active">Link 2</a>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```